# Resolve new files merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a merge/rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

How can I tell to git to automatically add new files in the moved directory ?

after all files moved in a sub-directory (just move, without any changes) on `main` branch, rebase of feature branches are easy except when new files has been created on the feature branch.

For each new file, git detect a conflict and I didn't find a way to solve it automatically. But `git mergetool` knows how to solve it.

Example:

- On `feature/newfile` branch, one commit added the file `src/Entity/SomeNewFile.php`
- On `main` branch, whole `src` has been moved to `server/src`
- `git rebase main` give the following conflict:

```
CONFLICT (file location): src/Exception/SomeNewFile.php added in 82ca32d0c (Add new feature) inside a directory that was renamed in HEAD, suggesting it should perhaps be moved to server/src/Exception/SomeNewFile.php.
error: could not apply 82ca32d0c... Add new feature
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 82ca32d0c... Add new feature
```

The suggestion is correct, and I would like to tell git to use its suggestion instead of asking me to do it, but the `--strategy=theirs` doesn't work.

git mergetool help me to solve this, but I think a command might exists to avoid to type 3 commands

```
$ git mergetool 
Merging:
server/src/Entity/SomeNewFile.php

Deleted merge conflict for 'server/src/Entity/SomeNewFile.php':
  {local}: deleted
  {remote}: created file
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort?
```

Comment: Even if `--strategy=theirs` existed, it would work the same way that `--strategy=ours` works, and that would *not* do what you want. Perhaps you mean `-Xtheirs`? I don't know, though, whether it solves your problem.

Comment: @j6t (and Asenar): no, unfortunately the `-X` options do not affect high level (or "tree level") conflicts at all. There is currently no way to encourage Git to take its own suggestion here.